# session id store on index page

Tags: php, mysql

this is login.php and its header location is index.php and i want to store session id on index page but nothing has been shown

```
<?php
@extract($_POST);
include("config.php");


 $sql="select password,name,us.id as uid from us left join tblblo on (tblblo.maker=us.id) where name='$websitename'  and password=md5('$password')";

$result=$db->query($sql);


        if($count=mysql_num_rows($result)>0)

        {


             $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
             $_SESSION['name']=$row['name'];
             $_SESSION['id']=$row['uid'];





                    header("location:http://".$_SESSION['name'].".domain.com");

        }

        else
        {
        //$_SESSION['sess_msg']="Invalid Web Name or Password!Try Again.";
        //header("location:https://domain.com/login.php");
        //exit;
        }



?>
```

i want to store session id on index page but nothing has been shown

Comment: where is your session_start(); ?

Comment: try moving include("config.php"); above @extract($_POST);

Comment: Mixing up `procedural` & `object oriented` methods.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** It's always good to write `session_start();` in the very beginning of your code before outputting anything else..

```
<?php
session_start();
@extract($_POST);
include("config.php");
```

**2)** You're mixing up the *deprecated* `mysql` API's with the `object_oriented` ones.

Change this:

```
if($count=mysql_num_rows($result)>0)

        {


             $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
             $_SESSION['name']=$row['name'];
             $_SESSION['id']=$row['uid'];
```

To this:

```
$count = $result->num_rows;
    if($count > 0)
        {

             $row = $result->fetch_assoc()); 
             $_SESSION['name']=$row['name'];
             $_SESSION['id']=$row['uid'];
```

**3)** *this is login.php and its header location is index.php and i want to store session id on index page but nothing has been shown*

I think what you meant was to use/echo the session values on *index.php* rather *store*?

on your index.php (after successfully storing the sessions on login.php):

```
   <?php
        echo     $_SESSION['name'];
         echo    $_SESSION['id'];
   ?>
```

Comment: You are also mixing up the same.

Comment: @b0s3 would this be fine now? `x;)`

Comment: i echo $_SESSION['name'] it shows right result but  $_SESSION['id'] is still empty

Comment: @yupokadmin on your `login.php` `echo $_SESSION['id']=$row['uid'];` and see if you're getting any value?

Comment: @yupokadmin if you're getting the value then you _probably_ are messing up with it on the next page. see if you've correctly `echoed` it.

Comment: this is index.php
<?php
include("config.php");
@extract($_POST);
@extract($_GET);
echo $ch="select * from us  where id='".$_SESSION['id']."'";
?>
but id is empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90797/discussion-between-yupok-admin-and-hawaskapujaari).

Comment: @yupokadmin Kindly read my answer's 1) point again. Ps. try `echo $_SESSION['id'];` first